# Click on href link selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium and Python to try and click on each of the links shown.  the same class name is used for the different websites.

```
   `<div class="rp-table-col c7">
                        <span class="mobile-title">Action</span>
                        <a class="action" href="https://website.com" target="_blank">View</a>
                    </div>
    <div class="rp-table-col c7">
                        <span class="mobile-title">Action</span>
                        <a class="action" href="https://website2.com" target="_blank">View</a>
                    </div>`
 <div class="rp-table-col c7">
                        <span class="mobile-title">Action</span>
                        <a class="action" href="https://website3.com" target="_blank">View</a>
                    </div>`
 <div class="rp-table-col c7">
                        <span class="mobile-title">Action</span>
                        <a class="action" href="https://website4.com" target="_blank">View</a>
                    </div>`
```

so far I'm able to get the 'View' text of all the classes but what I want to do is click on each of the links in the href (website, website2, website3, etc...)

```
y_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class*='rp-table-col c7']")
```

Comment: What happens when you try to click on them?

Comment: Didn't you try changing the selector to a link specific one?  if you are using xpath something like  `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'website.com')]").click()` should work. I mean since you have the link list, you can loop through and create the xpaths right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select all links and click them one by one using:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Some code
links = [div.find_element_by_tag_name('a') for div in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('rp-table-col c7')]
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

**Warning!** You must consider the possibility if clicking them switched the control to the new tab. So, I think you have the URLs saved in the `links` (list of `<a>` tags) variable, which you must use one by one by navigating to each URL. The `links[0].get_attribute('href')` will give you the first webdite URL.